# Azure Function - Python

Tags: azure-functions

Hi guys I am fairly new to Azure. I have a basic question , I am trying to create a Azure function using Python. Can I develop it directly on Azure Portal, or is it necessary to develop it using VS code and then deploy it to Azure function.

Comment: You can develop in Portal also, I would suggest doing it at first in local and the publishing would be good.

Comment: I have some firewall issue which doesnt allow me to connect to azure from Vscode, thats why thinking to do it in portal directly

Comment: Yeah you can do that in Portal, Try to share the error blocking in the question

Answer (score 1):

> Can I develop it directly on Azure Portal, or is it necessary to develop it using VS code and then deploy it to Azure function. Yes, you can develop it in portal by following below process:

- Firstly, Create a function app then open your function app
- Then click on Functions
- Then click on create
- Then click on Develop environment (choose what you want)
- Then click on Create 
  [image]

-- Your Function will get created. I would suggest you to create firstly on local to get hands on Functions and then try it on Azure.

-- If you create in local, you need to publish it to azure after coding it.